# generar figura que cambie de color cada vez que se regenera y funciones extras

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un curso introductorio a `js` y para finalizarlo debo generar la siguiente figura.

1- Que la figura inicial sea una línea y ésta se va transformando en rectángulo, luego en cuadrado y finalmente desaparece.

2- Hacer que la figura cambie de color cada vez que se genera.

3- Crear una función que cuando el usuario hace un clic en pantalla, cambie el color de la figura y además, en un párrafo se indiquen sus dimensiones (largo y alto).

Tenía estos problemas en un principio

1- La figura cambia de color solo si se recarga la página y no cuando se genera nuevamente.

2- en la función de click, la figura no cambia de color y no me arroja el alto y al ancho, sino que me arroja la posición en positivo y también en negativo, algo así como (210,-210),

Y actualmente arroja

> "Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext')"

o

> "numeroAzar is not a function".

El código es el siguiente:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("mi canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var posicion = 0;
var tamano = 0;
var largo = 1;
var alto = 400;
let color = ["Orange", "Red", "Blue", "Pink", "Green", "Purple", "Brown", "Skyblue", "DeepPink"];
var numeroAzar = Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length);


setInterval(function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
  ctx.fillRect(posicion, 0, tamano, 400 - tamano);
  colorAleatorio = color[numeroAzar];
  ctx.fillStyle = colorAleatorio;

  tamano++;
  posicion++;

  if (posicion > 400) {
    posicion = 0;
    largo = 1;
    alto = 400;
    ctx.fillStyle = color[numeroAzar(color.length)];
  }
}, 0);

$("#canvas").click(function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = color[numeroAzar(color.length)];
  $("#distancia").text("El largo de la figura es = " + largo + " y el alto es = " + alto);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Mision JS2 para finalizar curso</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="distancia"></p>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  <script>
    src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Cualquier ayuda la agradecería!

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia. Debes limitarla a un problema específico e ir desglosando los demás problemas en preguntas independientes. Te sugiero conocer la comunidad a través de [este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Primer problema detectado: No existe un elemento que tenga este `id` "mi canvas"

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mi canvas");
```

- Segundo problema detectado: No existe una función `numeroAzar` declarada sino que es una variable, por lo tanto no la puedes usar así:

```
ctx.fillStyle = color[numeroAzar(color.length)];
```

- Tercer problema detectado: No estás importando correctamente `jQuery`

```
src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"
```

Por ahora te corrijo esos tres errores, con esto ya no se muestran errores en la consola. Intenta solucionar los demás y regresa a generar una nueva pregunta si tienes más problemas.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var posicion = 0;
var tamano = 0;
var largo = 1;
var alto = 400;
let color = ["Orange", "Red", "Blue", "Pink", "Green", "Purple", "Brown", "Skyblue", "DeepPink"];
var numeroAzar = Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length);

setInterval(function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
  ctx.fillRect(posicion, 0, tamano, 400 - tamano);
  colorAleatorio = color[numeroAzar];
  ctx.fillStyle = colorAleatorio;

  tamano++;
  posicion++;

  if (posicion > 400) {
    posicion = 0;
    largo = 1;
    alto = 400;
    ctx.fillStyle = color[numeroAzar];
  }
}, 0);

$("#canvas").click(function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = color[numeroAzar];
  $("#distancia").text("El largo de la figura es = " + largo + " y el alto es = " + alto);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Mision JS2 para finalizar curso</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="distancia"></p>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```